# How can I calculate how many possibilties there are for a password

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, soft-question, contest-math

If there is a password that is 1000 characters long consisting of uppercase and lowercase letters and numbers what would be the possibility of someone figuring it out/how long would it take for someone to figure it out?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The answer depends on the methods the someone is allowed to use. Bribery, torture, hypnosis, ....

Answer (score 1):

As Gerry Myerson notes, the question is very unclear. Although, I can tell you one thing: the number of possible different passcodes. This tells you lots of different things, e.g. the probability of a random passcode being correct.

To compute this number, notice that for each digit, there are
$$\underbrace{26}_{upper case}+\underbrace{26}_{lowercase}+\underbrace{10}_{digit}=62$$
So since there are $62$ possibilities for each character, and $1000$ characters, there are thus $62^{1000}$ possibilities for the passcode.

Comment: If the fastest computer (442 petaflops according to Google) tried all possibilities, it'd take around $10^{1774}$ seconds, so unimaginably out of perspective I'm not even going to try to put it in perspective.